# TypeError: 'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
Ship_Date        Id

2019-10-29       i1 
2019-10-29       i2
2019-10-28       i3
2019-10-28       i4

2 years data
```

```
df_updated=df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False).set_index("Date").last("2M")
```

When I am trying to execute about piece of code getting error like,

> " TypeError: 'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index "

Any help would be appreciate
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` is not a datetime object. You need to cast to `datetime` first with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False).set_index("Date").last("2M")

           Id
Date          
2019-10-29  i1
2019-10-29  i2
2019-10-28  i3
2019-10-28  i4
```

---

Or you could also do:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pop('Date'))
df.sort_index().last('2M')

           Id
Date          
2019-10-29  i1
2019-10-29  i2
2019-10-28  i3
2019-10-28  i4
```

Comment: Thanks its working and I need to drop last 2 months records from DataFrame, I'm trying to removing by using drop but getting error like keyerror.